# how to prove this ( about surjective functions and inverse functions)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I  was making excercises for an upcoming exam and when trying to make this one I really got stuck.

The question is:

Prove that a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is surjective if and only if there exists a function $g$ from $Y$ to $X$ with $g$ after $f$ is the unit function (the function that maps every $x$ on $x$).

My thoughts directly went to the inverse function but than I started having doubts because if the domain is bigger than the co-domain the inverse function would have to have more than one value for every input and than g wouldn't be a function.

My second thought was the same but with a reduced domain so that f becomes bijective but I do't think thats allowed in this question.

Does someone know a way to solve/proof this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is surjective. We want to define a function $g: Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g = \operatorname{Id}_Y$. Well, given $y \in Y$, we know that there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. So define $g$ by choosing exactly one such $x$: that is, define $g$ by $g(y) = x$ for each $y \in Y$, where $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $X$ such that $f(x) = y$ (and such an $x$ is guaranteed to exist because $f$ is surjective). In that case, the composition $g \circ f$ acts on each $y \in Y$ by $(f \circ g)(y) = f(g(y))= y$ by our construction of $g$, and hence the composition satisfies the desired property.

Conversely, suppose there exists $g: Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g = \operatorname{Id}_Y$. We want to prove $f$ is surjective, i.e to each $y \in Y$ we want to find $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. Well, since $f \circ g = \operatorname{Id}_Y$, then for each $y \in Y$, $f(g(y)) = y$. So letting $x = g(y)$ we get $f(x) = y$, as desired. Therefore $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explenation, it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Michielvaganee you're welcome. If you want to, you can click the checkmark right next to the upvote button to accept my answer if you feel it was helpful. This helps those who answer the questions :)

Comment: I tried but i need 15 reputation since it's my first question i don't have it yet but when I do i'll defenitly vote up!!

Comment: @Michielvaganee No problem, but accepting an answer (clicking the checkmark) doesn't require having reputation - upvoting does, but not accepting.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to think about an inverse function in a strong sense. There is a more general terminology of left inverse and right inverse. In this case you have to proof the equivalence:

If $f\colon X\to Y$ is surjective, then there exists a function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$. Which means that $g$ is right inverse to $f$. (Here you write it differently in the task. Maybe a typo or confusion with the notation)

Also you have to proof that when there is a function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_Y$, then $f$ is already surjective.

The first statement is more difficult, as you have to construct a suitable function $g$.
But "difficult" is a relative term. What makes it difficult is that there are some ways to go wrong, or to get confused. For example you have to make sure, that your function $g$ is well-defined.

The second implication is straightforward.

In any case your first step should be to recall the definitions.
Look up what *surjective* means, and when a function is said to be *well-defined*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show the existence of an inverse, because the inverse may not exist, if $f$ isn't 1-1. You are supposed to show the right inverse, that is a function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g = \mathrm{id}_Y$.

You are right that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ can have more than one element. Take just one of them, that is define $g(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Comment: yeah that's something i thought about since severel people bring this up, i think it's the correct way, thanks for the help!!